# twitterscraper not working properly (scrapes zero tweets in the end and crashes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, twitter, tweets

The following scrapes zero tweets in the end and crashes. Can you please help me identify the issue?

```py
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

begin_date=dt.date(2019,3,4)
end_date=dt.date(2019,8,16)

limit=500
lang='english'

tweets=query_tweets('@HamidMirPAK',begindate=begin_date,enddate=end_date,limit=limit,lang=lang)
df=pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in tweets)
df1 = df[['text']]
export_csv = df1.to_csv (r'C:/Users/usama/Desktop/123.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this can be fixed by modifying the header dictionary in query.py from

```
HEADER = {'User-Agent': random.choice(HEADERS_LIST)}
```

to

```
HEADER = {'User-Agent': random.choice(HEADERS_LIST), 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

that should fix the issue.

Comment: Twitter’s user Terms of Service do not allow web scraping. Use the official API instead.

Comment: Is this a recent change? Judging by the many pre-made scraping packages which all are solutions for limitations within the official API